# Android API versus Java API for Google+ Search

Tags: android, google-plus

**tl;dr: How do you do a Google+ keyword search using the `com.google.android.gms` library?  Can you use the OAuth token, or do you need an API key?  (Yes, I know that token is overkill for the application.)**

I'm attempting to write an app that will search Google+ for a particular word, and then display results.  I followed the Android-specific [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android).  That works fine, but it's only signing in...which maybe isn't even required.  I don't care about user profiles or anything.  I just want to search and show results.  But whatever.  It's working.  Let's call that part A.

Part B is the actual search.  I found [another](https://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities/search#examples) sample code for that, but it's for Java, not necessarily Android.  Here's where the problem is.  I'm getting a 403 when I try to search, and I could show you the results of that, but it's the same as you'll find all over - "Access Not Configured"...which I did configure.  I spent a lot of time regenerating keys, and it seems like a dead end in a way.

But my question, that I'm finally getting to the point of, is about the two samples, and how they differ.  Part A, which is Android specific, has a package of `com.google.android.gms`, but part B, which is plain Java, has a package of `com.google.api`.  So, I can log in through the Android library and it works, but that package doesn't seem to include anything to allow searching, and the plain Java package gives me that access error, which is nonsense because I already have the OAuth token...in a seemingly incompatible API.

Why are there separate packages?  Should I ditch the Android one completely?  I'm considering ditching native Android code entirely and just using HTTP, which seems a lot simpler.